# Load Data Transfer Object To DataGridView Based On Object Passed

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I know similar questions have been asked with regards returning anonymous object type. But mine looks slightly different, because I just want to load data to the datagridview based on the patient object that was passed. But so far, the data returned from the query I made does not load based on the patient that was passed. But all other data works well.
I have created a data transfer object (DTo) which carries some data based on the query I wrote. Because I just need some selected columns returned. Below is my DTo class

```
 public class CaseNoteDto
 {
        //public patient Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
 }
```

Here is my query where I am using the DTo to load some data which I want returned.

```
 private IQueryable<CaseNoteDto> LoadCaseNoteBaseOnPatientId(patient patient)
 {
    var patientCaseNote =
        from c in dbHelper.casenotes
        join u in dbHelper.users on c.creator_id equals u.user_id
        join cat in dbHelper.categories on c.category_id equals cat.category_id
        where patient.patient_id == _currentPatient.patient_id
        //where _currentPatient.patient_id == patient.patient_id
        select new CaseNoteDto
        { 
            //Id = patient,
            CreatedBy = u.firstname,
            CategoryName = cat.name,
           // CreatedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(c.created_at)
        };
    return patientCaseNote;
 }
```

Here is where I am loading it to datagridview object and passing the currentPatient obj.

```
 private void PatientMasterData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var data = LoadCaseNoteBaseOnPatientId(_currentPatient);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated to tell me where I got it wrong. Because I just want the returned data to load based on the patient obj passed.

Comment: The data is returned but it's NOT showing in the DataGridView control, that's your question? or data is NOT being returned at all?

Comment: data is returned but it does not show based on the patient obj passed. i want the data to load only the patient info  based on the patient obj that was passed..